# Activity Working on emulator but doesn't load on tablet

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, the problem is that all activities work fine on emulator but one of the activity doesn't load on tablet (Running 4.4 kitkat) and stopes the Application, MainPage.Class is not working.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smarttrack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" > 

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.MainPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
             <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.AskActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
             <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.AskLocation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
             <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.Options"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
             <activity
            android:name="com.smarttrack.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

              <receiver android:name="com.smarttrack.MsgBroadcast">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainPage.Class**

```
package com.smarttrack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageView img;
    TextView statusText;
    String status ;
    Button askActivity;
    Button askLocation;
    Button addActivity;
    Button optionsMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        initVars();
        img.setOnClickListener(this);
        askActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
        askLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
        addActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
        optionsMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    private void initVars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.switchingImage);
        statusText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appStatus);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
        status = "active";

        askActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AskActivity);
        askLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAskLocation);
        addActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addActivity);
        optionsMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionsButton);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id){
        case R.id.switchingImage:
            Runnable swap = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(status == "active"){
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
                        statusText.setText("Status = Running");
                        status = "unactive";
                    }else {
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_on);
                        statusText.setText("Status = Stopped");
                        status = "active";
                    }
                }

            };
            img.postDelayed(swap, 100);
            break;

        case R.id.AskActivity:
            Intent  i = new Intent(this,AskActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btAskLocation:
            Intent loc = new Intent(this,AskLocation.class);
            startActivity(loc);
            break;
        case R.id.addActivity:

            break;
        case R.id.optionsButton:
            Intent opt = new Intent(this,Options.class);
            startActivity(opt);
            break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_item, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ActionBarHelp:
            AlertDialog.Builder bldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            bldr.setTitle("SmartTrack").setMessage("Cool application");

            Dialog dlg = bldr.create();
            dlg.show();

            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 4):

in your manifest xml your target sdk is 18 but 4.4 can run on 19

Comment: but all other activities work just fine without any problem, only this activity creates problem. moreover this activity once worked on tablet but later on it stopped working